# Can't fetch using JPA @NativeQuery with @OneToMany. JPA join query execute after native query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, jpql, nativequery

I'm trying to fetch data using native query. But below queries execute.

Native query:
`Hibernate: select * from employee emp inner join department dep on emp.id = dep.dp_id where emp.id=? and dep.department=?`

`Hibernate: select department0_.dp_id as dp_id3_0_0_, department0_.d_id as d_id1_0_0_, department0_.d_id as d_id1_0_1_, department0_.department as departme2_0_1_ from department department0_ where department0_.dp_id=?`

How to stop execute second query?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "dp_id")
    private List<Department> departments;

    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long dId;
    
    private String department;
    
    ...
}
```

Please let me know how to execute only native query?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the association to

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Answer (score 0):

User user = (User) session.createQuery("FROM User U WHERE U.username = :userName").setParameter("userName", userName)
.uniqueResult();

In hibernate, you will write a native query like this

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are accessing the `departments` collection, but as you see in the first query, the contents of that collection aren't loaded initially. Either you avoid accessing the collection to not trigger the lazy loading, or you fetch the collection along in the original query. Either by using entity graphs or join fetching. With join fetching, you can use a query like this: `select e from Employee e join fetch e.departments where e.id = :id`